# When does a pointer to a linked list change the actual list?

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list, reference

I have a singly-linked-list, L, and create a pointer to this list P. It seems like sometimes modifying P changes the actual list, while other times modifying P does nothing to the actual list L and only changes what P is pointing to.

Suppose I create a pointer to L, P = L (in python). Doing something like P = P.next leaves L unchanged, but P.next = P.next.next changes L. Similarly, changing the actual data stored in the list by modifying P.data actually changes L.data.

Why does this happen? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about pointers/references.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

    def addNode(self, val):
        root = self
        while root.next is not None:
            root = root.next
        root.next = Node(val)

    def iterateLL(self):
        root = self
        print
        while root is not None:
            print(str(root.val) + " ", end="")
            root = root.next
        print()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    L = Node(1)
    L.addNode(2)
    L.addNode(3)
    L.addNode(4)

    # iterate through list and print:
    L.iterateLL()

    # changing value of pointer does not affect L
    P = L
    P = P.next
    L.iterateLL() # L is unchanged

    # changing "next" value of pointer does affect L
    P = L 
    P.next = P.next.next
    L.iterateLL() # now we've skipped node 2

    # changing data of pointer does affect L
    P = L
    P.val = 10
    L.iterateLL()
```

The above code executes with the following output (first line shows the original linked list, second line shows that the list is unchanged following a change to the pointer P, while the third and fourth lines show that the list is changed)

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 3 4

10 3 4

What's going on here? Why does changing P not affect L, but changing P.next and P.val do? If all of these actions behaved the same way, wouldn't changing the pointer either *always* change the linked-list (and so P = P.next should modify L by getting rid of the first node), or *never* change the linked-list (and thus P.next = P.next.next should leave L unchanged)?

I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that L.next is a pointer, just like P.next. So modifying P.next ends up modifying what L.next points to (?). But I feel like the rules aren't clear to me.

Comment: There are no pointers in python

Comment: If I'm pointing my finger at you, and I start pointing at Joe instead, that doesn't affect you or Joe. If I go up to you and point *your* finger at whoever Joe was pointing their finger at, that *does* affect you.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Almost everything in Python is a pointer, Python just hides them pretty well. Most people don't even think about the fact that the variables they're working with are just pointers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In **most** cases in Python, when you perform an assignment on a variable, `P` in this case, the value of `P` changes, but the object that it was originally referring to does not. This is because Python variables are simply references/pointers to objects. Here is an example:

```
var1 = "test1"
var2 = "test2"
var3 = var1 # var3 = "test1"
var1 = var2 # var1 = "test2"

print(var1) # "test2"
print(var2) # "test2"
print(var3) # "test1"
```

So what is happening here? Well we are just changing what these variables are pointing to, we are not changing the underlying object.

Now in your case, you do the following:

```
# changing value of pointer does not affect L
P = L
P = P.next
L.iterateLL() # L is unchanged
```

When you do `P = L` and `P = P.next`, you are simply just changing what the variable `P` is pointing to. You are not making changes to the underlying object that `P` points to. Let's visualize it.

Original Configuration:
[image: Original Configuration]

```
P = L
```

[image: P = L]

```
P = L.next
```

[image: P = L.next]

However, when you do

```
P = L
P.next = P.next.next
L.iterateLL() # we've now skipped node two
```

You are changing an attribute of the object that `P` is pointing to. You are setting the attribute `P.next` to point to `P.next.next`. You are not actually making changes to the underlying object that `P.next` was originally pointing to. By doing this, the object that `P.next` was originally pointing to goes out of scope and is cleaned up by the garbage collector.

```
P.next = P.next.next
```

[image: P.next = P.next.next]

Judging by your code, I assume that your intended behavior in this case was to remove `L` from the LinkedList and end up with a list like so "2 3 4". To accomplish this, it should be sufficient to do `L = L.next`. This will cause the first node to go out of scope and the garbage collector should clean it up.

As a quick caveat, I mentioned that in **most** cases, assignment does not make changes to the object that a variable is pointing to. However, properties are a bit different. They override the `__set__` magic method which allows you to edit the underlying object using the assignment operator. This is not the case here.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the thoughtful response. This also explains why setting P.val = newVal also changes L.val to newVal. (In this case I didn't have an intended use for the code, I was just trying to figure out what happens with these pointers in linked lists)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote,

```
# changing "next" value of pointer does not affect L
P = L
P = P.next
L.iterateLL() # L is unchanged
```

However, you did not ***change*** the next value. You ***read*** from `P.next`. `P.next` was on the right-hand-side of the assignment. In order to change `P.next`, `P.next` would have to be on the left-hand-side of the assignment operator (`=`)

Then you write:

```
# changing "next.next" value of pointer does affect L
P = L 
P.next = P.next.next
L.iterateLL() # now we've skipped node 2
```

This time `P.next` is on the left-hand-side of the assignment operator (`=`). Therefore, you actually changed it.

```
write_to = read_from
```

Comment: I agree that I’m not changing P.next, and so I agree that the comment is misleading. But by setting P=P.next, P is now 2->3->4, while L is still 1->2->3->4. So if I had instead written in the comment “changing value of pointer”, I think the question still stands

Comment: @mcc: If you have to think in terms of pointers, then think about it like this. `P = whatever` is assigning one pointer to another pointer. This doesn't affect anything the pointers are pointing to. `P.next = whatever` is also assigning one pointer to another pointer, which doesn't affect anything the pointers are pointing to... but the pointer you're assigning to is a member of another object, and that member is now pointing somewhere new.

Answer (score 0):

One key understanding here is -

**Every variable in python is a reference (act as pointer) to an object i.e. a class instance**

For example, lets look at `Student()` class

```
S1 = Student()  # Creates a new instance of the Student class and assigns it's reference to S1
S2 = S1         # Assigns the reference to the same instance to S2
```

Here, S1 and S2 both reference the same instance of the `Student()` class.
In Python, when you do `S2=S1`, `S2` refers to the same object `S1` is referring to. It does not create a new object, and it's not a pointer to `S1`.

Now, coming to your problem,

1. `P = L` ==> you assign the reference to the same instance which is assigned to L, to P
2. `P = P.next` ==> you reassign P to the next node of P leaving the original object unchanged and hence L is unchanged.
3. If you do `P.next = P.next.next` instead ==> you are assigning the next node of P.next to P.next. There is a change in the actual data stored. Since the object's reference is also assigned to L, L.data will also change.

However, if you just want to create a new independent copy of the object, you can do a shallow copy like this

```
import copy

S1 = Student()
S2 = copy.copy(S1)
```

Here, modifications to one won't affect the other.