# Python: Assigned value to new variable from original, assign new value to new variable but original value change as well

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am reading this question:

[When does a pointer to a linked list change the actual list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759348/when-does-a-pointer-to-a-linked-list-change-the-actual-list)

code here:

```
typclass Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

    def addNode(self, val):
        root = self
        while root.next is not None:
            root = root.next
        root.next = Node(val)

    def iterateLL(self):
        root = self
        print
        while root is not None:
            print(str(root.val) + " ", end="")
            root = root.next
        print()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    L = Node(1)
    L.addNode(2)
    L.addNode(3)
    L.addNode(4)

    # iterate through list and print:
    L.iterateLL()

    # changing value of pointer does not affect L
    P = L
    P = P.next
    L.iterateLL() # L is unchanged

    # changing "next" value of pointer does affect L
    P = L 
    P.next = P.next.next
    L.iterateLL() # now we've skipped node 2

    # changing data of pointer does affect L
    P = L
    P.val = 10
    L.iterateLL()e here
```

I do not understand here why "L.iterateLL" value is changed when we modify P or any action on P. If it is "P.iterateLL" then I can fully understand since P read all the data from L; however, now it is iterate L which has not change anything actually. From my understanding P=L is one way reference that P read from L and not changing L.
Thus why L data is changed when we amend P? or here P=L is also L=P?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you assign P=L, it does not create a new object of that class, it simply assigns the address of that object. You can check the same by using `print(id(L), id(P))`. you will find that both the variable L and P are referring to the same object in the memory. And therefore changing P is the same as changing L.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I change the data inside P's list, it will also reflect in L. Then what is the purpose or benefit of using the new variable name?
for example, I am doing the Leetcode test and find one of the solution below. Cur is good enough but still creating dummy. there maybe some benefit?

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/solutions/1826693/python3-merging-explained/

Comment: The cur and dummy both are referring to the same object. you can check their ID as mentioned in my answer. For a list object having the same data but a different memory address, first, create an empty list variable then append the list with data to it.